# How to do this in android kotlin, not using visibilty gone, invisible

Tags: android-listview, android-cardview, expandable

[card_view expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2zw0.png)

I was not try to do with visibilty mode. I think it is not the appropriate way. You should use another way. For example, expandaple recyclerview or something, I am a junoir developer and I must do it for my resume guys helpt me!!!